# Undo hitting "I'm tired of this song" in Pandora

Tags: pandora

Is there any way to undo "I'm tired of this song" in Pandora? I accidentally hit it but I really would like to hear it as often as possible.  Any way to undo this mistake?

Answer (score 2):

For 'Thumbs Up' and 'Thumbs Down', you can remove the effect by going to "My Profile", selecting the station involved (you might only have one), and then finding the appropriate section (e.g. 'Thumbed-down tracks').  Find the song's entry in that list and click the 'x' to remove it.  For 'I'm tired; don't play for awhile', I don't know of a way to explicitly control it.

Answer (score 2):

After 30 days, it will come back.

This is from their blog:
"Now there’s a way to tell Pandora that you’ve heard something one too many times: just click Guide Us and select the “I’m tired of this song” choice and we’ll put the current song back on the shelf and not play it again on any of your stations in the next 30 days."

http://blog.pandora.com/2006/03/27/progress/

Comment: It's not 30 days because I clicked "I'm tired of this track" for Timber by Pitbull ft. Ke$ha on April 17th and it is now July 21st and it still has not played again. My solution to this is not hit that feature and create a new account and cancel the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find an "undo" button, but you can bring up the song and give it a "thumbs up".  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and could not find anyway to actually undo it. For a current workaround, occasionally pause Pandora and play the song you accidentally told Pandora you were tired of.